# Using triangles on low poly models

Tags: modeling, workflow, topology

I see alot of low poly models using triangles on specific parts. I know this workflow can help reduce the amount of tris, and even help with joints deformations. But for some parts I’m not sure why triangles were even used, (like the shoulders of the examples posted down below). Is it supposed to reduce shading issues for stretched quads or something like that? Thanks for answering!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You said it: help with joint deformations. The shoulder is a particularly complicated joint because it's a 'ball and socket' tyoe of joint, meaning it can move and rotate in all axis, so it's important to have better control of how it deforms.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, any model you create will be converted into triangles eventually by the game engine. Sometimes the engine makes a bad decision for which way it should triangulate the polygon. When it does, the texture stretches wrongly, also as a form itself may look broken. That's why on the extremely low poly models you may find some polygons triangulated by the modelers

Answer (score 1):

Probably because of smooth shaded normals.  Edges act to sort of *block* the propagation of normals.

Compare the normals and topology of these two simple shapes:

[image]

It's just a quad, loop cut in half, and then I've moved one of the vertices down.  And on the right, I've triangulated a face.  Notice how that affects the normals?

Every mesh is eventually triangulated, it's true.  However, before that happens, face and vertex normals are calculated.  On the triangulated mesh, those are three different face normals; two of them contribute to the vertex normal of the middle left vertex, but all three contribute to the vertex normal of the middle right vertex.  But on the untriangulated model, both face normals contribute equally to both middle vertices.

Because custom normals and tangent space normal maps both rely on the base normal, this remains true even when those are in use.  Of course, for a non-deforming model, it wouldn't matter-- you'd just give it the custom normals you want, and those would never change.  But on a deforming model, those are going to change as faces deform.

So by triangulating some faces in a mesh, you can control the influence of other vertices on the normals.  Sometimes you want that, and sometimes you don't.